# Passing data to modal and converting string to html not showing the output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- I have fetched some information of a particular point using `mapbox api`, I am trying to send the information fetched from that api to modal as a string and then using `react-html-parser` I am trying to convert the `string` into `html` code.
- The string is properly printed in the console the code that I want but while passing only the header of the table is displayed on the modal not the whole code.
- Code for fetching the information from `mapbox api`

```
// load a popup on mouse click and get specific coordinate information
      map.current.on('click', function(e) {

        // opening form modal for building features
        //setitemBuilding(itemBuilding)
        closeModalBuilding()
        openModalBuilding()

        var coordinates = e.lngLat;
        var lng = coordinates.lng;
        var lat = coordinates.lat;
        console.log(lat);
        console.log(lng);
        var d = fetch("https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + lng + "," + lat + ".json?access_token=<access_token>").then(response => response.json()).then(function(data) {
          console.log(data)
           }

          // form for editing and saving the building features and uploading images
          var itemBuilding = "<table><tr><td><label>Title</label></td><br><td><label>Content</label></td></tr><form>"
          for (let i in data["features"]) {
            itemBuilding += "<tr><td><label>" + data["features"][i]["place_type"][0] + "</label></td><td><input type='text' value='" + data["features"][i]["place_name"] + "'></input></td></tr>"
            // itemBuilding += itemBuilding + itemBuilding
          }

          // upload image with id, text, image
          itemBuilding += "<tr><td><label>Upload Image</label></td></tr><tr><td><label>ID</label></td><td><input type='text'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>Text</label></td><td><input type='text'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>Image</label></td><td><input type='file' name='filename'></input></td></tr></form></table>"
          console.log("Printing="+itemBuilding)
          setitemBuilding(itemBuilding)

          new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(coordinates)
            .setHTML(itemBuilding)
            .addTo(map.current)
        }
        );
        console.log(d);


      });
```

- Modal Code

```
<Modal
        isOpen={modalIsOpenBuilding}
        
        onRequestClose={closeModalBuilding}
        style={customStyles}
       >

       <center><b><h1>Building Features</h1></b></center>
       <br/>
       <br/>
        <Form>
            <Form.Field >
              
            {ReactHtmlParser(itemBuilding)}
      
             </Form.Field >
        <br/>
        <br />
        <Form.Group>
        <Form.Field style={{marginLeft:"8%"}}>
          <Button color="blue" onClick={closeModalBuilding}>Close</Button>
         </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field style={{marginLeft:"15%"}}>
      
        <Button color="green" onClick={UploadForm}>Done</Button>
         </Form.Field>
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>


</Modal>
```

- The above code gives me the below output

[image]

- And the HTML code from the console log

```
Printing=<table><tr><td><label>Title</label></td><br><td><label>Content</label></td></tr><form><tr><td><label>address</label></td><td><input type='text' value='5416 Kentland Farms Road, Blacksburg, Virginia 24060, United States'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>postcode</label></td><td><input type='text' value='Blacksburg, Virginia 24060, United States'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>place</label></td><td><input type='text' value='Blacksburg, Virginia, United States'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>district</label></td><td><input type='text' value='Montgomery County, Virginia, United States'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>region</label></td><td><input type='text' value='Virginia, United States'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>country</label></td><td><input type='text' value='United States'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>Upload Image</label></td></tr><tr><td><label>ID</label></td><td><input type='text'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>Text</label></td><td><input type='text'></input></td></tr><tr><td><label>Image</label></td><td><input type='file' name='filename'></input></td></tr></form></table>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post the table as plaintext? Images expire and we can't copy the text to test ourselves.

Comment: You're including a `form` element at the top level inside the table which is breaking it. You can move the form to the outside: `<form><table>...</table></form>`